# Error getting an item from json file in Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, json-query

I am trying to get the subnets from a json query in Ansible. My debug is result is as below:

```
"msg": [
    {
    "address_prefix": "10.10.2.0/23",
    "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/MYVNET/subnets/MySubnet",
    "name": "MySubnet",
    "network_security_group": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx/resourceGroups/MYVNET/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/mynsg",
    "provisioning_state": "Succeeded",
    "route_table": null
    }
]
```

I am trying to get the name of the subnet. My Ansible play is as below:

```
  tasks:
    - name: "Retrieve resourcegroup infos"
      azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info:
      register: object_vnet

    - name: get subnet name 
      debug: msg='{{ item.value }}'
      with_dict: "{{ object_vnet.virtualnetworks }}"
      when:
        - item.key == 'subnets'
        - item.value.name is match *MySub*
```

The error that I get , is as below:

```
        fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'item.value.name is match *-MySub*' failed. 
The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected 'end of statement block'. 
    String: {% if item.value.name is match *MySub* %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\n
    The error appears to be in '/myplay.yml': line 41, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\n
    The offending line appears to be:\n\n\n - name: get subnet name\n ^ here\n"}
```

Any ideas to help?

Comment: => `item.value.name is match "MySub"`. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings . Note that this will fix the syntax error but I'm quite sure you will get an other error (something like `object_vnet.virtualnetworks is not a dict` since it is a list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subnets are a list, so you need to loop on subnets objects of your vnets and loop on all subnets in a vnet.

to do this, you can create a separate file to loop and you subnets and loop on this file:

### loopfile:

```
- name: create facts azure_subnets_result
  set_fact: 
    azure_subnets_result: >-
      {{
        ( azure_subnets_result | default([]) )
        + [ az_sub_item ]
      }}
  loop_control:
    loop_var: az_sub_item
  loop: "{{ az_sub }}"
  when: (az_sub_item.name | lower ) is match(".*mysub.*")
```

### main file:

```
tasks:
    - name: "Retrieve resourcegroup infos"
      azure_rm_virtualnetwork_info:
      register: object_vnet

    - name: create azure_subnets object
      set_fact: 
        azure_subnets: "{{ object_vnet.virtualnetworks | json_query(vnet_query) }}"
      vars:
        vnet_query: "[*].subnets"

    - name: loop on all object subnets and all sub objects
      include_tasks: loop.yml
      loop_control:
        loop_var: az_sub
      loop: "{{ azure_subnets }}"


    - name: debug message
      debug: msg='{{ azure_subnets_result }}'
```